# custom about window for OSX application

Tags: macos, menu, osx-mavericks

I am working on small application and i am new to osx programming, i have searched all over but I didnt find how to show custom about window.

In my application i have 3 controllers one for log in and then i switch to other but third one is About but I dont know how to change when someone click on about menu, i have come to know that `orderfrontstandardaboutpanel`  called but how i gonna use it to show my view? this is my

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    _accountDetails = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    self.loginViewController = [[MTLoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MTLoginViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.loginViewController.delegate = self;
    // 2. Add the view controller to the Window's content view
    [self.window.contentView addSubview:self.loginViewController.view];
    // [self setUIWindowsFrame:self.loginViewController.view.frame];
     self.loginViewController.view.frame = ((NSView*)self.window.contentView).bounds;
}
```

Comment: I assume you can display a normal About Panel, to make a custom Panel you would override `orderFrontStandardAboutPanel` or `orderFrontStandardAboutPanelWithOptions`